# chin up more difficult than pullups?

Tags: exercise, muscle

Since the distance from chin to bar is greater for narrow grip chin ups compared to wide grip used for pullups why are chin ups not considered the more difficult exercise to perform?

Comment: Some people https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/42432/why-are-chin-ups-harder-than-pull-ups do consider chin-ups the more difficult exercise.